# Continuous map from $\mathbb C^4$ to $\mathbb R$ that changes sign under circular permutation of coordinates and that is $0$ only for squares

Tags: plane-geometry

Does there exist a continuous map $f$ from $\mathbb C^4$ to $\mathbb R$ such that:

i) there exists four distinct complex numbers $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, s.t. $f(a,b,c,d)f(b,c,d,a)<0$

ii) for every $(x,y,z,t)\in \mathbb C^4$, $f(x,y,z,t)=0$ implies that $x$, $y$, $z$, $t$ are the corners of a square in the complex plane?

---

This is related to the [inscribed square problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_square_problem).

Indeed, let's say that a polygon defined by $(a,b,c,d)$ is $f$-good if it satisfies the condition i), then an approach to solve the inscribed square problem can be to prove that there exists $f$ such that any Jordan curve contain a $f$-good polygon.

Comment: How does $f$ being a polynomial ("polynome") justify the tag "model theory"?

Comment: I guess for definissable sets, do you think i should remove this tag?

Comment: Whatever definissable sets are, I do not thing the tag is appropriate.

Comment: The problem if f is a polynome is related  to a first order formula in the theory of ordered fields, isn't it?

Comment: Not every question about polynomials is a question about model theory. But what does it mean for $(x,y,z,t)$ to be a square?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Perhaps those four complex numbers form the corners of a square in the complex plane?

Comment: i mean they are the vertices of a square i.e. they satisfy $|x-y| = |y-z| = |z-t|= |t-x| $ and $|x-z|=|y-t|$. I used  $\mathbb C$ instead of $\mathbb R^2$ for presentation, but same equalities hold by replacing $|a+bi|$  by $a^2+b^2$ , so that the problem might be enounced in first order in some more general context.

Comment: See the [Inscribed Square Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_square_problem): "Does every plane simple closed curve contain all four vertices of some square?"

Comment: @ Joseph O'Rourke, we almost  posted at the same time. that is why i don't mension your comment, but endeed, you had the right interoretation... maybe I should edit the main post to avoid misunderstanding...

Comment: Thank you Joseph O'Rourke, i mention this problem in the question but i now have a link ... that i m going to open right now , and add the in the question!

Comment: @Gerry Myerson $f$ is real valued.

Comment: I realized that I didn't post what I wanted, and that I previously switched quantificator in the i) , i'm going to ask a new question, by replacing "there exists" by  "for all" ... or for an in between question, replace there exists in i) by for all , but with some condition on the type of thz polygone  xyzt , this condition should be that there is a polygone of this type in any Jordan curve (why not triangles...)

Comment: I saved the question of uselessity in case of an eventual trivial positive  answer by  an edit at the end, that take in consideration and give an issue to what I wrote in my upper comment. I also removed the tag model theory

Comment: @LSpice, thank you very much for the english grammar  and presentation edit !

Comment: i don't inderstand the upvotes of the comments, especially the one of Gerry Myerson,  that does not give an example, because as I said it just after, f is supposed to be real valued...Actually the question can be answer by the negative, and I'm going to explain why in an answer, in a moment.

Comment: The idea is that if $abcd$ is not a square, one can find a path from it to $bcda$ such that no 4-gon on the path is a square. This is a contradiction because as require in the hypothesis $f(a,b,c,d)$ and $f(b,c,d,a)$ have a different sign, so $f$ continuous has to take the value $0$ for some 4-gone on the path, and this can happend only if  the 4-gon is a square.

Comment: The disproof has been given by the great Anatole Khelif ! Anatole just answered now to the question "do you mind if I mention your name?" in a contrast, he took just one minut to answer by mail and by the negative, the question of the post!